# Counter-intuitive preg_match behavior - what is the cleanest way to match a range of characters?

Tags: php, regex, hex, preg-match, chr

I am looking for ways to match a range of characters and assumed the following regEx would only match characters in the range of hex codes between 20 and 7E. However, it also matches `chr(10)` (line feed), in fact, the following prints "passed":

```
echo preg_match("/^[\x20-\x7E]*$/", chr(10)) ? 'passed' : 'failed';
```

Any idea why and how to match that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chr(10) is end of line, so you should add [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) D.

> If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines).

```
//                               v
echo preg_match("/^[\x20-\x7E]*$/D", chr(10)) ? 'passed' : 'failed';
//                               ^
```

Comment: ...or use `\A` and `\z` instead of `^`  and `$` to force anchoring at the very start and end of the string.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Nevertheless, isn't M42 correct that the star is optional and the regex will pass not just for form feeds but like `chr(14)` even if you have used `\A` or `\z`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, you are right. It's better to use \A and \z cause pattern would be independent from PHP.

Comment: @Sniffer: No. The anchors are there to ensure that the entire string matches, and `chr(14)` is definitely outside of the range defined by the character class. The problem is that `chr(10)` is treated specially by `$`, as sectus correctly states.

Comment: @Sniffer, This is the [Escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: @TimPietzcker I see I see I see, I don't know how I missed that. It happens sometimes. Anyway everything is OK now. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Many thanks, both solutions by @sectus and @TimPietzcker work great! I see now that the new line `chr(10)` is treated specially by `$`, which I still find counter-intuitive, there are sadly no examples in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php)

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: Read about [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) here, especially the section "String ending with a Line Break".

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, fantastic tutorial! The best I've seen! So none of the two solution works in JavaScript! Arrgh! Have to use /m option instead.